# Right click on OSX new item

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa, right-click

I would like to advice from you. It is possible to add new item to right click on `OSX`? For example I select any word in safari, TextEdit, Notes, Pages, Preview and I would like send this word to the server and get response. It is possible? Can you give me any hint how should I start?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SysServices/introduction.html

Comment: Oh and https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/   specifically share extensions

Comment: Do you have any better examples? Thank you

Comment: I don't know what else you are asking, by this point, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent {

    NSMenu *theMenu = [[NSMenu alloc] initWithTitle:@"Contextual Menu"];

    [theMenu insertItemWithTitle:@"Beep" action:@selector(beep:) keyEquivalent:@"" atIndex:0];

    [theMenu insertItemWithTitle:@"Honk" action:@selector(honk:) keyEquivalent:@"" atIndex:1];

    [NSMenu popUpContextMenu:theMenu withEvent:theEvent forView:self];

}
```

Read more [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MenuList/Articles/DisplayContextMenu.html).